# How can I fix the table heading in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I fix the table heading in XSLT?
I have a HTML table designed using XSLT. I want to fix the table heading while scrolling down to the bottom.

Comment: Start by finding out how to do this in HTML. Then, if necessary, ask how to produce the required HTML code in XSLT.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Refer this link: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_sticky_header

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time to do homework assignments for your question. Post all the code necessary to demonstrate your problem within your question - see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tried to implement it.
(3) Desired output.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.